# Change KMS encryption key on existing AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

Given already deployed AWS resources that use the default AWS managed keys, is it possible to change the default encryption key from AWS managed to a Customer Managed Key (CMK)?

Resources in question:

- EFS
- FSx

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change it, at least the API documentation don't have this options.

EFS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/API_UpdateFileSystem.html

FSx:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateFileSystem.html

Comment: So...uh...how do you do key rotation?

Comment: You need to create a new file system with Customer Managed CMK and move your file to it. Using Amazon Managed CMK you don't have any control on key.